# Convert Vertex TabularDataSet to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I train a scikit learn model with a Pandas dataframe.
My data preparation job produce a parquet file and a Vertex Tabular Dataset.
I use parquet file as input to train my model but I'd like to use vertex Dataset instead.

I can get it in training job using
`dataset = aiplatform.TabularDataset('projects/project_id/locations/europe-west4/datasets/dataset_id')`
but I need to convert it in a Panda DataFrame.

Is there a way to convert a Vertex DataSet to a Panda DataFrame?

Thanks'